# compare two dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

How do i campare dictionaries that contain dictionaries ?

This will work in case the dictionaries contain simple values

```
# will show the keys with different values

d1_keys = set(dict1.keys())
d2_keys = set(dict2.keys())
intersect_keys = d1_keys.intersection(d2_keys)
modified = {}
for i in intersect_keys:
     if dict1[i] != dict2[i] : modified.update({i : (dict1[i], dict2[i])})
```

but i have a dictionary like this:

```
{ 'medic1' : {'date' : '02/02/2015', 'no' : '123' }, 'medic2' : {'date' :'02/03/2015', 'no' : '456' }}
```

Comment: What do you mean "compare"?  From your example, it looks like you're trying to somehow create a new dictionary that combines them, but you use an undefined variable `o`.  Please explain what result you want.

Comment: my mistake for the undefined variable. the result i want is to print out (i chose a dict to it )  the keys that have been modifed in the dict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By recursion function for nested dictionary.

1. Get common keys from both dictionary by `keys()` and `set operation.`
2. Iterate common keys by `for` loop.
3. Check `type` of value of key is `dict` or not.
4. If value type is `dict` then call same function and pass values dictionary as arguments. and add result as key into `modified` dictionary.
5. If value type is not dict then add into `modified` dictionary.

code:

```
dict1 = { 
        'medic1' : {'date' : '02/02/2015', 'no' : '123' }, 
        'medic2' : {'date' : '02/03/2015', 'no' : '456' },
        'testkey1': 'testvalue1',
        'testkey2': 'testvalue2',
        'testkey3':{ "level2_1":"value2_1", 
            "level2_2":{ 
                        "level3_1": "value3_1_change", 
                        "level3_2": "value3_2", 
                    }
        }
}

dict2 = { 
        'medic1' : {'date' : '02/02/2015', 'no' : '456' }, 
        'medic2' : {'date' : '02/03/2015', 'no' : '456' },
        'testkey1': 'testvalue1',
        'testkey2': 'testvalue22',
        'testkey3':{ "level2_1":"value2_1", 
                    "level2_2":{ 
                                "level3_1": "value3_1", 
                                "level3_2": "value3_2", 
                            }
                }

}

import copy

def compareDict(dict1, dict2):

    d1_keys = dict1.keys()
    d2_keys = dict2.keys()
    intersect_keys = set(d1_keys).intersection(set(d2_keys))
    modified = {}
    for i in intersect_keys:
        if dict1[i] != dict2[i] : 
            if isinstance(dict1[i], dict) and isinstance(dict1[i], dict):
                modified[i]=compareDict(dict1[i], dict2[i])
            else:
                modified.update({i : (dict1[i], dict2[i])})

    return copy.deepcopy(modified)


modified = compareDict(dict1, dict2)
import pprint
pprint.pprint(modified)
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 5.py 
{'medic1': {'no': ('123', '456')},
 'testkey2': ('testvalue2', 'testvalue22'),
 'testkey3': {'level2_2': {'level3_1': ('value3_1_change', 'value3_1')}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the **keys** are hashable (which a `dict` guarantees!-) it doesn't matter whether the **values** are or not -- code like:

```
common_keys = set(dict1).intersection(dict2)
```

(a simplified version of your first three lines), then

```
modified = {k: (dict1[k], dict2[k])
            for k in common_keys if dict1[k] != dict2[k]}
```

(a simplified version of your last three lines) will work fine!